# Need help extracting just the IP address

Tags: python, ip

I am writing a python script that reads all the `.html` files in a folder, searches them for IP addresses, and then returns the IP addresses.

Currently if my script finds an IP address, it returns a bunch of stuff:

```
print result
<re.Match object; span=(21, 30), match='10.6.0.25'>
```

Any suggestions on how I can get just the IP address?

Sorry if my question and terms are vague or incorrect. I'm very new at this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import glob
import re
import ipaddress

#Get html files in directory and put them in reports variable
reports_list = glob.glob("*.html")

#opens all reports, and reads through them one by one
for current_report in reports_list:
#opens the current report
    with open(current_report) as input:
        #reads current line from input
        for line in input:
            ip_search_result = re.search(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}", line)
            if ip_search_result is not None:
#removes the "none" entries
                ip_search_result = re.search(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line)
                print(ip_search_result)
```

Comment: I see that you are reading `.html` files. Do the files have some structure from where you can extract the IP address? You can then use HTML parser.

Comment: inside your `for`loop change first line from `re.search` to  `re.findall` , then print the `ip_search_result` n check if that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DOM parser and extract the URL links and eventually the IP addresses.

An alternative is to use regular expressions matching IP addresses.